# Prevent invalid input based on regex?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have got this regex expression

```
ng-pattern="/^[A-Åa-å -]{0,2}[0-9 ,-]+$/"
```

It does its job, but what i am trying to figure out, is it possible to prevent the user from getting it typed inn if it is unvalid.

Hopefully based on a regex so i dont need to check all the keycodes?

Comment: Can you extend the explanation a little more? What you want the user can't do if the pattern not match?

Comment: Basicly i want the user not beeing able to get the charater they pushed into the input field if it doesnt match the regex validation. So if i press first 22 and then press a. the a shouldnt come into the input field

Comment: Like, every time they press a key validate it?

Comment: yes and prevent it to come into the input field if it is not valid

Comment: You can't do it that way, because the user never gonna match the pattern, so you basically gonna have a disabled input. You need a different approach, like cutting the expression and doesn't permit the user to write the next part of the pattern without validating the previous one.